# Difference between anhören, lauschen, hinhören and hinhorchen

Tags: vocabulary

Are there any subtle differences in meaning between anhören, lauschen, hinhören and hinhorchen, all of which has got something to do with listening?

Comment: I had been told that AUDI (the car firm) was an acronym of **A**uto **U**nion **D**eutsche **I**ndustrie

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Anhören** focuses on the intent of listening.

> Ich höre das Lied. *(I hear the song.)*
>
> Ich höre (mir) das Lied an. *(I intentionally listen to the song.)*

---

**Lauschen** means *to eavesdrop*!

> Sie lauscht. *(She eavesdrops.)*
>
> Ich lausche dem Lied. *(I try to figure out the gentle parts of the song.)*
>
> Ich lausche deiner Stimme. *(I listen to your (gentle) voice. — either sweet-talk or sarcastic.)*

BUT:

> She **be**lauscht die Nachbarn. *(She eavesdrops on the neighbors.)*

---

**Hinhören** is intentional, careful and visible listening to something. It's similar to **zuhören** but points to an item which is not the speaker.

> Ich habe eine Idee. Hör zu! *(I have an idea. Listen to me!)*
>
> Die Tür quietscht. Hör hin! *(The door creaks. Listen to it!)*

---

**Horchen** means putting your ear very near to something which makes a sound.

Some dialects prefer it instead of **hören** and also use **hinhorchen**. It means the same as *hinhören* then. Similar for *abhören*.

> Horch mal! *(Listen to me carefully!)*

In other dialects *horchen* is a synonym for *lauschen* instead.

> Horch mal! *(Put your ear here and listen carefully!)*

---

DID YOU KNOW? The car brand *Audi* is named after its founder *Horch*, after he was dismissed from the first car company he founded under his own name. *Audi* means *Listen!* in Latin, so does *Horch!* in German.

---

**Lauscher** and **Horcher** are common comical names for the ears.

> Sperr mal die Lauscher auf. *(Listen! – literally: Unlock your eavesdrop-tools.)*